# Show the total of a column in the top of a table

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have a table and content of the column are coming from a Database. In the bottom of the table I am able to show the total value as well. But I want to show the total at the top of the table because sometimes there are hundreds of Rows, and to see the total I have to scroll to the end.

Is that even possible?

I have tried the below code. Which is giving me the total at the end of the table. But I want to show the total at the top of the table

```
<Table>
// This will create the column names
// I need to get the Total here above these column names
<tr>
  <td> Product </td>
  <td> Qty </td>
  <td> Price </td>
</tr> 

<% set ObjRS =ObjConn.execute ( "select * from pricetable")
 total= 0
 Do while Not ObjRS.EOf
  product = objrs("product")
  qty = objrs("Quantity")
  price = ObjRS("price")
  total = total+ price
  response.write "<td>" & product & "</td><td>" & qty & "</td><td>" & price & "</td><td>"

objrs.movenext
loop

response.write "<tr><td> & Total & </tr></td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from

```
response.write "<tr><td> & total & </td></tr>"
```

to

```
response.write "<thead><tr><th> & total & </th></tr></thead>
```

Comment: The problem is we are getting the Total value at the end. So how can we reflect the Total value at the top.

Comment: It will at the top, replace to thead tag

Comment: let me try..Thanks

Comment: It will place it above the header though and destroy the meaning of `th` which is `table heading` meaning the description of the elements inside this column.

Answer (score 1):

You could just temporarily save the output and then output it in the order you like (I don't know the language you are using there, so there might be some slight changes to make, but in general that would be the most basic solution):

```
<Table>
// This will create the column names
// I need to get the Total here above these column names
<tr>
  <td> Product </td>
  <td> Qty </td>
  <td> Price </td>
</tr> 

<% set ObjRS =ObjConn.execute ( "select * from pricetable")
 sum = 0
 outText = ""
 Do while Not ObjRS.EOf
  product = objrs("product")
  qty = objrs("Quantity")
  price = ObjRS("price")
  total = sum + price
  outText = outText & "<tr><td>" & product & "</td><td>" & qty & "</td><td>" & price & "</td></tr>"

objrs.movenext
loop

response.write "<tr><td> & total & </td></tr>"
response.write outText

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help.. really appreciated it :)

Comment: No problem. If it helped you and your problem is solved, please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: @user2922926 Be careful with this approach because if you have a lot of records by building up the string beforehand you could reach the response buffer limit. If you set `Response.Buffer = True` you can call `Response.Flush` periodically through the loop using `Mod` to only flush the buffer every so many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a second query that calculates the SUM().

Vbscript can have buffer issues if you try to loop through and assign it all to variables — especially for a lot of data.  The thead trick is hack-ish and undermines your structure. Best to calculate the sum directly